# Converting flash drive from RAW to exFAT and restoring it original storage capacity

Tags: usb-flash-drive

My flash of 1TB became 8MB and its system type showed RAW rather than exFAT when I used it to transfer some document and after some while when I try using it again it shows me that I should format it. So, I did that but I didn't work. I have used disk manager, command prompt, disk genius to convert it back to the original system capacity and system type but none are working.

Comment: Your 1TB flash drive, are we talking an actual 1TB flash drive, or a 1TB ssd?

Comment: Sounds like a dead drive.

Comment: When you say it "became" can you describe what led up to this, or how you discovered this? If the drive spontaneously just became this smaller size it is likely the drive has died. More information can help us understand better what may be going on.

Answer (score 2):

You should have done the following:

1. Removed *all* partitions, and confirmed completion.
2. Created a single partition, and confirmed.
3. Formatted that partition, and confirmed.

If the device does not show as ~1 TB, then it's dead.

The emphasis on confirming each step is because most drive tools require a second step to apply changes to reduce risk of error. For example, in DiskGenius, "Click Save All button to save changes to partition table." It's easy to accidentally omit that step, effectively canceling the operation.